# jquery append not working in Rails ajax view

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My app is on Rails 4.1.1 with jquery.

The page displays a list of activities, each contained in a partial.

For each activity, user can add a new comment -- the id of the link_to new comment method is dynamically based on the activity id, i.e. #newcomment_185.

For each activity, the comments are displayed in a list --- the id of the ul is dynamcally based on the activity id, i.e. #commentslist_185.

```
_activity.html.erb (my activity partial)
<p>The activity content is here.
<%= link_to t('new_comment'), new_activity_comment_path(activity_id: activity.id), :id => "newcomment_#{activity.id}", remote: true, :class => "button tiny " %></p>
<ul id="commentslist_<%= activity.id %> "> Comments: <%= activity.comments.count %>
 <% activity.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <li> <%= comment.body %> (par <%= comment.commenter.name %>) </li> 
<% end %>
</ul>

comments_controller.erb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @comment = Comment.new commenter: current_user, activity_id: params[:activity_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if request.xhr?
        format.js
        format.html { render layout: false }
      else
        format.js { render :action => 'new' }
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment }
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.commenter = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Commentaire ajouté' }
      else
        format.js { render 'update' }
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :activity_id, :commenter_id)
  end
end

/app/views/comments/new.js.erb
$('#newcomment_<%= @comment.activity_id.to_s %>').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
$('#commentform').slideDown(350);

/app/views/comments/create.js.erb
$('#commentform_<%= @comment.activity_id.to_s %>').remove();
$('#newcomment_<%= @comment.activity_id.to_s %>').show();
$('#commentslist_<%= @comment.activity_id.to_s %> ul').append('<%= j render(@comment) %>');
```

The problem is with this last line --- everything works but this. The li element is not added to the ul.

In the Chrome console preview the parsed js seems ok :

```
$('#commentform_188').remove();
$('#newcomment_188').show();
$('#commentslist_188 ul').append('<li> test 1 (by John Doe) <\/li>');
```

There's no error message anywhere. I have tried different versions of that last line --- without ul, alternating single quotes and doubles quotes, etc. I am clueless. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've added an extra space that break your selector:

```
<="commentslist_<%= activity.id %> ">
<="commentslist_<%= activity.id %>">
```

Comment: I did not realize an extra space after the name would break the selector. Good catch ! Thanks.